# To create key value pairs according to user input in an array in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, key-value

I need to create an array of key-value pairs to a key `"availabilities"` according to user inputs in the following format to post the data. Confused about how to do that.

```
"availabilities": [
    {
        "availabilites_start_time": "6:00",
        "availabilites_end_time": "10:00",
        "availabilites_dayofweek": "1.",
        "availabilites_shift": "Morning"
    }
],
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Does my answer works for you?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will helps:

```
var availabilitiesDict = [String: Any]()
availabilitiesDict["availabilities"] = [["availabilites_start_time" : "6:00", "availabilites_end_time": "10:00", "availabilites_dayofweek" : "1.", "availabilites_shift" : "Morning"]]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: availabilitiesDict, options: [])
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all **create a Struct as a data model** and **one array as data source** as shown in below code.

```
struct Availabilities {
let availabilites_start_time, availabilites_end_time, availabilites_dayofweek, availabilites_shift : String 
}

var availabilitiesArray = [Availabilities]()
```

We get memberwise initializers for free, so whenever user Picks his choices create an instance of Availabilities with those values as shown in below code snippet.

```
 let availability = Availabilities (availabilites_start_time: "6:00", availabilites_end_time: "10:00", availabilites_dayofweek: "1", availabilites_shift:"Morning" )
```

Since you have a codable type struct, you can use JSONEncoder to convert your type to Data which can be either written to a file or sent over the network.

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(availability)

let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
print(jsonString)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I will suggest 1st create the inside array of dictionary then outside dictionary.**

```
    var myData = [String:Any]()
    var dataArray = [[String:Any]]()
    var finalDict = [String : Any]()

    myData["availabilites_start_time"] = "6:00"
    myData["availabilites_end_time"] = "10:00"
    myData["availabilites_dayofweek"] = "1."
    myData["availabilites_shift"] = "Morning"

    dataArray.append(myData)
    finalDict["availabilities"] = dataArray

    print(finalDict)

 let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: finalDict, options: [])
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)
```